# How to apply an entire script with many calculations to every column in a data.frame

Tags: r, loops

I need to **apply a number of calculations to one single column** in a data frame.
For this, I extract the column, create a new data frame and then start building up on this with new columns that contain mainly easy calculations. 
**Then I need to repeat this** (quite long script) to every column in the data frame.

**Apply family doesn't work because I can't manage to put all my calculations in one function(x)**

My original data frame looks like this, where S are Site Numbers and the values are biomass (years 1981:2007 and sites S1:S25).
I want the script below to be applied to every single column (every site) and a separate output data frame per column.

my data.frame is called ts.bio,  it includes NA's

```
    year S1 S2 S3  S4  S5  S6  S7 S8  S9 S10 S11 S12 S13 S14 S15
    1981 94 91 92 103 162 104 125 91 108 101 117 138 115  95  99
    1982 33 52 52  73 109  40  41 55  51  77  77 100  54  44  62
    1983 26 14 30  29  46  14  16 25  11  24  31  31  19  11  28
```

This is the Script that I need to apply to every column

```
    change<-NULL

    for (i in 1881:2007){
      lambda<-tsBio$S1[tsBio$year==i+1]/tsBio$S1[tsBio$year==i]
      change<-c(change, lambda)
         }


    print(change)

    #edit the data frame 
    change<-as.data.frame(change)  
    change$t<-c(1:26)    #add time 
    change$year<-c(1982:2007)   #add year 

    # I need DataCombine for the Insert Row line 
    library("DataCombine")
    NewRow<-c(0, 0, 1981)   #create new row
    change<-InsertRow(change, NewRow, RowNum=1) #ad new row

    change$biomass<- tsBio$S1   #add population size


    #create a lagged version to compute delta for differentiated B      (B')
    change$changelag<-change$change #duplicate column
    change$biomasslag<-change$biomass #duplicate column 
    change$tlag<-change$t


    #before this I need to detach dataCombine and activate data.table
    detach("package:DataCombine", unload=TRUE)
    library("data.table")
    change$changelag<-shift(change$changelag, n=1, type="lag")
    change$biomasslag<-shift(change$biomasslag, n=1, type="lag")
    change$tlag<-shift(change$tlag, n=1, type="lag")


    #compute nominator and denominator of differentiated B (B')
    change$deltaB<-(change$change-change$changelag)
    change$deltaX<- (change$biomass - change$biomasslag)

    change$Bdiff<-(change$deltaB/change$deltaX) 

    #compute mortality differentiated
    change$deltat<-(change$t-change$tlag)
    change$M<- change$change-(change$deltaX/change$deltat)

    change$Mdiff<-(change$M/change$biomass)

    change$lambda<-(change$Bdiff-change$Mdiff)

    library("ggplot2")
     ggplot(data=change, aes(x=year))+
     geom_point(aes(y=lambda))
```

I tried to use loops and apply family but can't manage to do anything. Creating one function (function(x)) to "lapply" seems crazy because there's so much content in the script.

Thanks sm for suggestions! And sorry for the dumbness.

Comment: Hello and welcome! Do you see any objective challenge to wrapping your script in a function, so that apply or map could be used? To me it sounds like your main issue is that the script is a mess and you don't want to rewrite it.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment. Actually I don't think my script is a mess. The main problem is just that I am not sure whether one function can do what my script does, because I am creating an entire new data.frame with new columns. Can a function do that? Maybe then I can pull just all my script in a function?

Comment: Yes, you can declare pretty much anything locally in a function. See e.g. this ebook if you want to read more about how R & functions work:  https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functions.html

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest restructuring your data from wide to long format and then using `dplyr`. In this case, each row would be for an observation and would have a column for year, site #, lambda, biomass, etc., and it would keep all your data in a single convenient data frame. Pulling data for certain sites, years, and such is easy using `filter`. Here's an example:

```r
# Create dummy data frame
df <- data.frame(year = 1981:2007,
                 t = 1:27,
                 S1 = sample(1:200, 27, replace = TRUE),
                 S2 = sample(1:200, 27, replace = TRUE),
                 S3 = sample(1:200, 27, replace = TRUE),
                 S4 = sample(1:200, 27, replace = TRUE),
                 S5 = sample(1:200, 27, replace = TRUE))

# Quick peak
head(df)
#>   year t  S1  S2  S3  S4  S5
#> 1 1981 1 163 133  86  59  40
#> 2 1982 2  99  28 190 179  58
#> 3 1983 3  94 136   6  47 185
#> 4 1984 4 199  87 137  31  20
#> 5 1985 5 157 169 172  24  21
#> 6 1986 6 105  33 189 122 148
```

This is the structure of your original data in wide format. Let's change it to long format and do some calculations.

```r
# Load libraries
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(tidyr)


# 1) Convert to long format
# 2) Group by site for calculations
# 3) Calculate lambda, change in biomass
# 4) Ungroup
df %<>% 
  gather(site, biomass, S1:S5) %>% 
  group_by(site) %>% 
  mutate(lambda = biomass/lag(biomass),
         delta_biomass = biomass - lag(biomass)) %>% 
  ungroup

# Quick peak
head(df)
# # A tibble: 6 x 6
#    year     t site  biomass  lambda delta_biomass
#   <int> <int> <chr>   <int>   <dbl>         <int>
# 1  1981     1 S1        175 NA                 NA
# 2  1982     2 S1         74  0.423           -101
# 3  1983     3 S1        177  2.39             103
# 4  1984     4 S1         15  0.0847          -162
# 5  1985     5 S1         28  1.87              13
# 6  1986     6 S1        150  5.36             122
```

Now your data is in long format and we did some calculations using `mutate`, which just adds some columns to your data frame. (It can also overwrite columns.) Notice that I didn't have to create any intermediate lagged columns in my calculations, I just used `lag`. In this way, you can add all your calculations without the need for any loops and it makes for clean, readable code. Also, restructuring the data like this means that you don't have to do this for each site column, as it's applied to all at the same time.

At first, it may seem cumbersome to have all these data together in one place, but it's actually really easy to pull the data you want from it using `filter`. For example:

```r
# Only see data for site S4 between 2000 and 2005
df %>% 
  filter(site == "S4", 
         between(year, 2000, 2005))
# # A tibble: 6 x 6
#     year     t site  biomass lambda delta_biomass
#    <int> <int> <chr>   <int>  <dbl>         <int>
# 1  2000    20 S4        124  1.38             34
# 2  2001    21 S4        116  0.935            -8
# 3  2002    22 S4        178  1.53             62
# 4  2003    23 S4         92  0.517           -86
# 5  2004    24 S4        107  1.16             15
# 6  2005    25 S4         87  0.813           -20
```

---

#### Edit

I missed out site grouping in the original version, which is now corrected.